# Bigquery Stackoverflow - Query closed questions by category

Tags: google-bigquery

## Background info

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), StackOverflow questions can be closed due to several reasons, namely *Duplicate of...*, *Off-topic because...*, *Needs details or clarity*, *Needs more focus* and *Opinion-based*.

Queries are executed on the public StackOverflow Bigquery on Google Cloud Platform.
This Bigquery contains, amongst other tables, *posts_questions* and *votes*, the first containing all questions and the second contains cast votes on these questions.

*posts_questions* schema:

| id | title | body | accepted_answer_id | answer_count | comment_count | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

*vote* Schema:

| id | creation_date | post_id | vote_type_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

## Question

There exist 16 different *vote_type_id*s and according to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678) on Meta, vote_type_id 6 corresponds to a close vote.
After three close votes were cast by users, a question appears as closed on StackOverflow.
The following query, therefore, returns the id and URL of 10 closed questions.

```
SELECT q.id, CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/', CAST(q.id as STRING)) as url,
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.votes` AS v
  ON q.id = v.post_id
WHERE v.vote_type_id = 6
GROUP BY q.id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
LIMIT 10
```

My question is, is it possible to query closed questions based on the close vote reason?
Like, query 250 questions that were closed due to being duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Like, [howto] query **questions** that where **closed due to being duplicates**?

You should use PostHistory table

> **PostHistoryTypeId**

- 10 = Post Closed - post voted to be closed

> **Comment**: This field will contain the comment made by the user who edited a post. If PostHistoryTypeId = 10, this field contains the CloseReasonId of the close reason

- 1 = Exact Duplicate
- 101 = Duplicate

So, finally - the query is

```
SELECT q.id, CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/', CAST(q.id as STRING)) as url,
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.post_history` AS h
  ON q.id = h.post_id
WHERE h.post_history_type_id = 10
AND h.comment in ('1', '101')
GROUP BY q.id
```

> My question is, is it possible to query **closed questions based on the close vote reason**?

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN comment IN ('1', '101') THEN 'Duplicate'
    WHEN comment = '102' THEN 'Off-topic'
    WHEN comment = '3' THEN 'Subjective and argumentative'
    WHEN comment = '4' THEN 'Not a real question'
    WHEN comment = '7' THEN 'Too localized'
    WHEN comment = '10' THEN 'General reference'
    WHEN comment = '20' THEN 'Noise or pointless (Meta sites only)'
    WHEN comment = '103' THEN '''Unclear what you're asking'''
    WHEN comment = '104' THEN 'Too broad'
    WHEN comment = '105' THEN 'Primarily opinion-based'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
  END close_reason,
  COUNT(DISTINCT q.id) cloased_posts
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.post_history` AS h
  ON q.id = h.post_id
WHERE h.post_history_type_id = 10
GROUP BY close_reason
ORDER BY cloased_posts DESC
```

with output

[image]